# Identifying Dragged Item

Tags: javascript

I am (once again) working on a drag and drop item and am unable (currently) to solve the following issue.

The segment of code that is of concern is:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {ev.preventDefault();}

function drag(ev) {ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Find out the name of the DIV you are dropping this in to
    var prntId = ev.target.parentNode.id;

    var tgt = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    alert ("ev.target.id = " + ev.target.id + "\n" + "prntId = " + prntId + "\n" + "tgt = " + tgt);
```

Quite simply, the alert should give me the ID for the item being dropped on to, the parent DIV of that item and the ID of the item being dropped (or the DIV that the item has been dragged from). However, it is this last piece of data that I cannot identify.

I have achieved this with images using almost identical code, but this time I have a  that is being dragged and dropped.

How can I identify the draggable item's ID, or the parent from which it came (either is fine)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code and here is what I ended up with. Please click "Run code snippet" and drag'n'drop a link into the square.

```js
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

document.getElementById('draggable_link').addEventListener('dragstart', drag);

// We have to add next 2 listeners to be able to "drop"
function dragover(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
function dragenter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var prntId = ev.target.parentNode.id;
    var tgt = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    alert("ev.target.id = " + ev.target.id + "\n" + "prntId = " + prntId + "\n" + "tgt = " + tgt);
}

document.getElementById('drop_zone').addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
document.getElementById('drop_zone').addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter);
document.getElementById('drop_zone').addEventListener('drop', drop);
```

```css
#drop_zone {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone_parent">
  <div id="drop_zone"></div>
</div>

<div id="drag_from_list">
  <a id="draggable_link" href="http://google.com">Drop me into the square</a>
</div>
```

Everything seems to be working right.

Please let me know if it helped. If not then please post a full version of your code to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) so I can debug it.

Comment: Sorry, should have recognised that you had replied!
Actually, I found another solution, in that I had no need to undertake the actual swap in the traditional way. The data is stored in a list, and I keep re-displaying the items via the list. So, all I actually needed to do was use the data I was acquiring to sort the list correctly. This doesn't make any sense, I know, but basically, I found a really good workaround. :)